# Facebook Page Tab app confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a Facebook Page Tab app which users can install while logged in to my application.

The problem is that I need a way to associate a user in my app with the Facebook user that authorizes it. I need this so that when any user goes to that tab in their page, I'll know which of my accounts is associated with the Facebook page that tabe is on.

Make sense?

When a user authorizes a Canvas app, all sorts of info comes back. But not with a Page Tab app. Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/

Comment: I've been reading that for 2 days. I get the signed_request when a user visits the tab, but I have no way to know which account in my application that user is associated with since I get nothing upon successful authorization.

Comment: You should get the users facebook ID when the user is authorized. Store that in your database and use the ID in the signed_request to sign the user in.

Comment: Oh! the authorization request returns and array tabs_added (poorly named) which is actually the page id's the app was added to. I can store that. I thought that was just the app id that was added. Sheesh, thanks.